# Do Kindred have an Oriental counterpart in nWoD?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

The closest to an "asian" Vampire I've seen so far is the Aswang described in Antagonists- are there other variations?

Answer (score 3):

The book *Night Horrors: the Wicked Dead* contains many variants on core vampires, creatures who are definitely vampiric in some sense but aren't quite Kindred.

One of these is the Jiang-Shi (p57). They are mortals who used a dark ritual to prevent themselves from dying, and turned into "hopping corpses". They have Blood Potency (always zero) and a Beast, and can learn a certain set of Disciplines and Devotions, but they don't go into torpor like Kindred and are almost impossible to kill. By committing Diablerie they may be able to "uplift" themselves into Kindred, but this is left as an ST option.

These are probably the closest equivalent to the Asian vampires in OWoD. They aren't very common, and the Kindred don't often interact with them, but they are part of VtR canon.

Answer (score 1):

In the main "canon" of nwod there is only one type of vampire existing.....the requiem one. All vampires are of this type. Thus there is no kindreds of the east in that sense as being a completely different race. They are just vampires as all others.

As you mentioned there are some books that bring up options there like antagonists. These books are mainly gm aids if he wants to add flavor and variations into the game if his group finds the next murderer commited by a "normal" vampire boring. They are not main canon though thus only the book they are in refers to these beings and no other book even acknowledges their existence. And of note is that often these options are grossly unbalanced when compared to other splats / the main canon (not only as npcs but also as player options some were quite underpowered and some were so brutally overpowered that it was just funny any more like changing breeds where almost every shapechanger has almost double or more of the werewolves dice bonuses and can get with just a few xp the same types of powers as the werewolves thus making them the weakest in the lot by far).

So to sum it up: Main canon there are no other types of vampires, but some books are adding things to add flavor. Also there are books like mirrors that give you options to modify vampires which theoretically you could use on just "groups" of vampires to create your own vampire sub species.

Edit:
The above also counts for VII. In the normal books they are just normal vampires. Their own book (VII) adds options for the gm to use in order to make them different from other vampires.